# Static button positioning in the panel java

Tags: java

I have this code but as soon as i expand or resize my frame, the button shifts to center position. I have tried to add simple panels and buttons, I need 2 panels equal size divided vertically/horizontally, each panel should have the button to the left side and text area to have some text output after buttons are clicked into respective panels.

```
package jobmonitor;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class PanelTry {

     static JTextArea jText = new JTextArea("");
     static JTextArea jText1= new JTextArea("");

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout(2,1); 
    f.setLayout(myLayout);
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setBorder ( new TitledBorder ( new EtchedBorder (), "" ) );
    button1 = new JButton("Server1");
    p1.setLayout(null);
    button1.setBounds(0, 5, 100, 20);
    p1.add(button1);
    f.add(p1);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setBorder ( new TitledBorder ( new EtchedBorder (), "" ) );
    button2 = new JButton("Server2");
    p2.setLayout(null);
    button2.setBounds(0, 20, 100, 20);
    p2.add(button2);
    f.add(p2);

    jText.setBounds(new Rectangle(100,20,500, 500));
    jText.setSize(800,300);
    jText.setEditable(false);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (jText);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    p1.add(scroll);

    jText1.setBounds(new Rectangle(100, 20,200, 200));
    jText1.setSize(800,300);
    jText1.setEditable(false);
    p1.add(jText);
    p2.add(jText1);


    // setLayout(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    f.setSize(700, 700);
    f.setVisible(true);



  }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the `BorderLayout` and give it a try. I think it may be its mistake. Layouts tend to move and resize components (in fact, it is their job)

Comment: If i remove, I see a blank panel with no division of the 2 panels or buttons.

Comment: Use `setLeftComponent` and `setRightComponent` instead of `add`.

Comment: I updated my code to above. I am trying to add scrollbar in my code but it is not showing up.